# Not able to use nsetools on Mac OS X 10.11.9

Tags: python, six

I am not able to use [nsetools](http://nsetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

```
sudo pip install nsetools
Password:
The directory '/Users/debraj/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/debraj/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting nsetools
 Downloading nsetools-1.0.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from nsetools)
Installing collected packages: nsetools
 Running setup.py install for nsetools ... done
Successfully installed nsetools-1.0.5
```

I tried installing `nsetools` without being a superuser. But it was throwing the below error:-

```
pip install nsetools
Collecting nsetools
  Downloading nsetools-1.0.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from nsetools)
Installing collected packages: nsetools
  Running setup.py install for nsetools ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/pip-build-nEc2HK/nsetools/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/pip-gh3BsV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/nsetools
    copying nsetools/__init__.py -> build/lib/nsetools
    copying nsetools/bases.py -> build/lib/nsetools
    copying nsetools/nse.py -> build/lib/nsetools
    copying nsetools/utils.py -> build/lib/nsetools
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nsetools
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nsetools': Permission denied

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/pip-build-nEc2HK/nsetools/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/pip-gh3BsV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/pip-build-nEc2HK/nsetools/
```

On trying to use `nsetools` I am getting the below error:-

```
python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 16:30:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nsetools import Nse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nsetools/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nse import Nse
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nsetools/nse.py", line 26, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

Even though I have `six` installed:-

```
sudo -H pip install six
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

Can someone let me know what is going wrong?

Comment: Why installing packages as a superuser?

Comment: I was getting error `error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nsetools': Permission denied` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise you not to install pip packages with `sudo`, instead read about using virtual environments with Python, such as [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). Without virtual environment you will constantly face errors such as the ones you mentioned.

This should help you with setting up the virtual environment:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv your_virtualenv_name
$ source your_virtualenv_name/bin/activate
(your_virtualenv_name) $ pip install nsetools
```

Read [this article](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to get the idea about virtual environments, their purpose and usage.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error I am getting when trying to install `nsetools` as normal user. I am getting the same error if I try importing `nsetools` by running `sudo python`.Also if I do `pip install six` without `sudo` it is saying `Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`

Comment: Updated my answer... Don't use sudo for installing pip packages! :) Instead, find a way to install them properly as a single user. Virtual environments should solve all your problems related to these kind of issues.

Comment: Since I have already installed now. Also doing `pip install nsetools` now shows the `Requirement is already satisfied`. Can you let me know how can I use `nsetools` now?

Comment: Trust me, don't go that way! :) Uninstall `nsetools` and `six`, install virtual environment, activate it and install those libraries in virtual environment. I will update my answer in a sec...